# wrapping text words in new line

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the below code for wrapping long text, entered by users in a text area for commenting:

```
function addNewlines(comments) {
  var result = '';
  while ($.trim(comments).length > 0) {

    result += comments.substring(0,70) + '\n';
    comments = comments.substring(70);
  }
  return result;
}
```

The problem is shown in the below screen shot. Any ideas on how to solve it? Can we use `lastindexof(" ")` method to get the last space in a substring to solve this issue logically? Can anyone tweak this little code to make it right?

[image: scrn shot of output]

Comment: Why can't you just put it in an element with a set width and let the browser handle wrapping the lines for you?

Comment: Java tag doesn't belong here.

Comment: Try using **Justification** css style for text area

Comment: but css doesnt work for all browsers

Comment: @tina you mean "specific CSS" I assume? CSS works in all browsers ;) That's the whole point :P

Comment: Using div and css style should be an easy way; otherwise, using Code style, you need think about: after comments.substring(), the next char mustn't be within('A'-'Z' and 'a'-'z').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe wrapping a text by CSS is a better solution however there is a link here which may be helpful [wrap-text-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript)

by the way i remember there is a JQuery plugin for wrapping text google it too.

Comment: hey thanks this works but for some capital letters it disrupts the alignment of my page

Comment: also its not giving me the whole sentence its cutting some last words

Comment: Note that if you're working with `.svg`, which doesn't support auto-text wrapping, it might be necessary to "manually" wrap text (via javascript). So it is a worthwhile question to ask how to do it in javascript specifically.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of these:

1. `word-wrap:no-wrap;`
2. `word-wrap: break-word`

It might solve your problem

Comment: tried it not wrking using css using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript but this again give prob for continous character entries like hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh

Comment: `no-wrap` is an invalid property-value for `word-wrap`, what you mean is `white-space` and `nowrap` of course (without hyphen), eh?! `word-wrap` has only these two values `normal | break-word` ;) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap

Answer (score 1):

Try `word-wrap: break-word` in CSS.
The `word-wrap` property is well supported by browsers (even IE 5.5+).
More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-wrap
Sample usage: [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EBm9f/)

Comment: could you tell me where to put these settings in jquery custom csss

Comment: I edited with an example. However, it does not guarantee, that text will be formatted grammatically correct.

Comment: @tina you can look into [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/injecting-word-breaks-with-javascript/) and try to implement this solution.

Answer (score 1):

The ones above only work 99% of the time.  This is the only one that works for me 100%: 
http://locutus.io/php/strings/wordwrap/

Answer (score 0):

Hi just apply some css on text area like

```
style="word-wrap: break-word;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this css code for displaying in Torch browser and it works

I've tried `word-wrap:break-word;overflow:ellipsis;`....etc, but didn't work.

```
#xxx{

 width: 750px;
 word-break: break-word;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

After looking for the perfect solution using regex and other implementations. I decided to right my own. It is not perfect however worked nice for my case, maybe it does not work properly when you have all your text in Upper case.

```js
function breakTextNicely(text, limit, breakpoints) {

  var parts = text.split(' ');
  var lines = [];
  text = parts[0];
  parts.shift();

  while (parts.length > 0) {
    var newText = `${text} ${parts[0]}`;

    if (newText.length > limit) {
      lines.push(`${text}\n`);
      breakpoints--;

      if (breakpoints === 0) {
        lines.push(parts.join(' '));
        break;
      } else {
       text = parts[0];
   }
    } else {
      text = newText;
    }
   parts.shift();
  }

  if (lines.length === 0) {
    return text;
  } else {
    return lines.join('');
  }
}

var mytext = 'this is my long text that you can break into multiple line sizes';
console.log( breakTextNicely(mytext, 20, 3) );
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I solved it using the below function.

```
function wordWrap(message, lineSize, breakPoint){
    let wordsArr = message.split(" "),
        wordsLen = wordsArr.length,
        finalMsg = "",
        linesArr = [""],
        currLine = 0;

    for(let i=0; i< wordsLen; i++){
        if(linesArr[currLine].length + wordsArr[i].length > lineSize){
            currLine +=1;
            linesArr[currLine] = wordsArr[i] + " ";
        } else {
            linesArr[currLine] += wordsArr[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    let linesLen = linesArr.length;
    for(let i=0; i<linesLen; i++){
        finalMsg += linesArr[i] + breakPoint;
    }
    return finalMsg.trim();
}
```

Hope this helps.