# How do I stop js alert from having an output like this?

Tags: javascript, firefox, alert

How do I make the alert data visible instead of the following output?

[image: "Prevent this page from creating additional dialogs"]

Comment: Firefox bug, file it on the bug tracker. On a side note, I wonder why the mozilla guys keep changing the ui. The old alert didn't have this problem and worked quite well. It also distinguished native alert boxes from html ones.

Comment: As a workaround, try breaking the word (by inserting some spaces in it) so the scroll bar ceases to be needed by the browser. If you are using for debug purposes, have you heard of `console.log()`?

Comment: Thanks guys. I need this to work for debugging on an iPhone, so I don't think console log will do it. I'll make a jquery dialog pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a wordwrap before presenting the text, like the one here: [wrapping text words in new line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16141095/wrapping-text-words-in-new-line)

```
alert(addNewlines("longtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtextlongtext") )
```

But I would follow @acdcjunior and use console.log("text") if for debug purposes.

Answer (score 2):

You could just not use an alert and instead use `console.log` for debug messages and `console.error` for actual error notification.