# wrap text and center align in javascript function by appending & prepending spaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, func

for (e.g) for a max 15 Word Line, if the input str="text acknowledgement" the the string should contain        str ="      text     acknowledgement"
basically adding spaces at the right place so that when i place in a 15 line Word Wrapping editor it should wrap and center align as shown below.

text     
acknowledgement

I am seeing a solution here [Wrap Text In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript/14487422#14487422) except it doesn't center align the words.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: For center alignment, you should be using a style setting.

Comment: 'Java' is to 'JavaScript' as 'Car' is to 'Carpet'.

Comment: I am not using HTML Elements or CSS but i am using canvas in my HTML5 hangman game, basically i already have a logic to draw blank dashes as long as the return string has blanks to center align , my game logic would work to display/draw the text.

Answer (score 0):

Aligning text by inserting space characters works ONLY in a very restricted environment: fixed-width horizontal space using a monospace font of a specific, known size.  Change any of those parameters (width, font, font-size) and your alignment will be off.

Alignment should be accomplished with CSS.

Comment: Yes i needed only for a specific purpose , check my comments above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
String.prototype.centerText = function(numberOfSpaces)
{
    var text = this;
    text = text.trim();
    var l = text.length;
    var w2 = Math.floor(numberOfSpaces / 2);
    var l2 = Math.floor(l / 2);
    var s = new Array(w2 - l2 + 1).join(" ");
    text = s + text + s;
    if (text.length < numberOfSpaces)
    {
        text += new Array(numberOfSpaces - text.length + 1).join(" ");
    }
    return text;
};
```

Usage:

```
var textToBeCentered = "Hello, World!";
var centeredText = textToBeCentered.centerText(40);
// centeredText = "              Hello, World!              ";
```

Comment: I think the OP is asking about an algorithm to get the correct number for a given line length. So if you had a 3-words string with total 10 chars, and the line length is 16, the OP needs the number 6 as a result which he can use. 
For eg., `input = "a good boy"; lineLength = 16;` => `output = "<3 spaces>a good boy<3 spaces>"`