# Not able to break a line inside a textarea where text wraps off and moves to next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textarea

I am building a web app for personalised merchandise. Requirement is to provide few text boxes to the user to get the input, push exactly the same format to the server and get it processed.I have textareas to take the inputs but have been struggling to push the same format as we see it in the browser.

Once the text exceeds the line width in the textarea, it moves on to another line. User would see the text spread across multiple lines though its one complete string. I plan to insert new line breaks at these points so that the text could be broken across multiple lines and that way I will be able to push the text in the same format to the server but its giving me a tough time.

Options provided to the user are fonts and their different sizes. Even for the same fontsize one line in the text area can accommodate different number of characters based on the width of the character typed. This is making the content unpredictable for breaking the line based on any pre-determined max character length.

I am somewhat able to achieve it if I hardcode the number of characters in a line and add '\n' through javascript but as I mentioned above this is spoiling the output. I am able to add new line breaks but only at hardcoded limits. Since characters have different widths, same constraint is not working correctly.

Example 1:
Inside textarea:

> Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for
>   the evil Queen and Jack.

Line wraps off after "brew for". When this text area content gets processed against a char limit of 34, the output I get is:

> Grumpy wizards make toxic brew for
>   the evil Queen and Jack.

Perfect replica as it looked in the text box, this is what was needed. Lets look at the next instance:

Example 2:
Inside text area:

> GRUMPY WIZARDS MAKE TOXIC BREW
>   FOR THE EVIL QUEEN AND JACK.

Line wraps immediately after "BREW". When this text area content gets processed, the output is:

> GRUMPY WIZARDS MAKE TOXIC BREW FOR
>   THE EVIL QUEEN AND JACK.

So as we see, though the line break occurred inside the text box immediately after "TOXIC BREW" what I could achieve was a break after "TOXIC BREW FOR" due to the hardcoded char limit. Not the same as I wanted.

So relying on a predetermined length and then adding '\n' to the respective break off points through javascript is not helping me out. Is there a way to detect where exactly the text gets wrapped so that I can precisely add new line breaks at those points? Not sure, if there is any better way to achieve the same?

Any help/pointers will be highly appreciated.

---

EDITED:

CSS:

```
textarea#lpt {
height: 150px;
width: 50%;
border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204);
/*font-size:20px;*/
}
```

JS: (Reference [Wrap Text In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript))

```
function stringDivider(str, width, spaceReplacer) {
    if (str.length>width) {
        var p=width
        for (;p>0 && str[p]!=' ';p--) {
        }
        if (p>0) {
            var left = str.substring(0, p);
            var right = str.substring(p+1);
            return left + spaceReplacer + stringDivider(right, width, spaceReplacer);
        }
    }
    return str;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit_text').click(function(){
        text = $('#lpt').val();
        alert("Original text submitted is: "+ "\n"+text);
        textWithBreaks = stringDivider(text, 34, "\n");
        alert("Processed Text is : "+"\n"+textWithBreaks);
    });

});
```

Adding a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/beetleport/aR2YH/2/) to demonstrate the scenario. Font size can be increased or decreased, the appearance in the text box changes but the output will be the same due to char limit. StringDivider function is a sample reference from another post on stack overflow.

Comment: woowow....too big a question....you mind showing the css/html too?

Comment: can you show your `javascript`?

Comment: Have added the css/js excerpts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the wrong approach. The best approach is to use the text width and comparing it with the left over width in the text area. This post [Calculating text width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582534/calculating-text-width-with-jquery) helped me to define a fake span element, adding text to it runtime and then calculating the actual width that can be accommodated.