# Break the string into two lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I want to break a string into two lines, but the line should not break into two, at the half of a word. How can I do this?

The string format is like this:

```
var words="value.eight.seven.six.five.four.three"
```

Expected output is:

```
"value.eight.seven.

six.five.four.three"
```

Comment: what is your expected O/P..? What do you mean by two lines..? want to store the split values into two variables..

Comment: you want to break string but still don't want to break in two. It is little confusing. Is it that you want to break it in two halfs but words should not break?

Comment: you have to be more specific. what is the point at which you want to break the string??

Comment: Check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript

It is similar to your issue, just need to change the identifier to break the line accordingly.

Comment: @ Bhushan Kawadkar:i mean the line should not break at middle of "seven", or "six", means it should break after the third word or the fourth word

Comment: Do you want to have space after seven. or <br>?

Comment: you could create an array and then split that in two and re-join.

Comment: i want break this into 2 lines

Comment: do you want to break this into 2 lines on the basis of size? i mean you want the first string to be broken into two halves of the same size?

Comment: @aradhna  OP is trying to split the string based on the dots and want to join them into a single string but made of two chunks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var words="value.eight.seven.six.five.four.three"
    var wordsArr = words.split(".");
    var line1 = wordsArr.slice(0,Math.floor(wordsArr.length/2)).join("."); 
    var line2 = wordsArr.slice(Math.floor(wordsArr.length/2)).join(".");
```

Here is the working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6xgS2/

Answer (score 3):

Try,

```
var words = "value.eight.seven.six.five.four.three";
var splitted = words.split('.');
var index = splitted.length / 2;  
var val1 = splitted.slice(0, index).join('.') + ".";
var val2 = splitted.slice(index, splitted.length).join('.');
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uLE4V/)

Comment: @Rajapraphu : out Of Topic .. check mail da

Answer (score 1):

you do the following-->

```
var words = "value.eight.seven.six.five.four.three";
var all = words.split(".");
var new="";  //empty string

for(var i=0;i<all.length;i++){
new=new+all[i]+".";  //add each word and the .
if(i==3)
new=new+"\n"; //add a \n after the third word
}
```

the new var will have your new string. 
hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var words = "value.eight.seven.six.five.four.three";

var all = words.split(".");
var half=all.length/2;
var first = all.slice(0, half).join();
var second = all.slice(half, all.length).join();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v9W6c/4/)

Comment: It will work only for the provided string, it's not a general answer, and I think OP is looking for a general solution which will work on any string.

Comment: @balachandran - OP ask to break the line you just splited

Comment: this edited answer is look like Rajaprabhu posted. Mahana inaki ne maatinada