# javascript line wrapping on width with html tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to do line wrapping with javascript (not css word-break or break-all) on the following text based on a width in pixels and keeping the html tags ?

I have the following html:

```
<div>
    <div class="line" id="line-5">
    <b style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-size: 11px;">
        <span class="author-basic">Lorem Ipsum</span>
    </b>
    <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-size: 11px;">
         <span class="author-basic">&nbsp;is</span>
    </span>
    <span style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans; font-size: 12px;">
        <span class="author-basic"> sietting industry. Lorem sietting industry. Lorem sietting industry. Lorem sietting industry. Lorem</span>
    </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript

Comment: No, because i asked this to be in pixels not in char langth