# split raw content and wrap element with wrap()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have bunch of text, they have 500 character, I want to split them into few section, so I thought of wrapping them with html tag, using `wrap()`.

How to do that since they are not selector html element?

https://jsbin.com/jirasevume/1/edit

```
var str = '0123456789';

for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ )
{
  console.log(str.charAt(i));
}

//group 2 characters into 1 group and wrap it with a div
```

Comment: provide html at least please.

Comment: @SergioAlen sorry missed my jsbin earlier.

Comment: so, just to clarify. `str` has to be split in groups of two characters? and wrap each group in a div?

Comment: @SergioAlen yes sir.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without the jQuery wrap function, specially seeing how they aren't HTML elements. For more information on how this works, refer to:

> http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

Here's a way to do it, in pure javascript, though.

```
var str = '0123456789';

for ( var i = 0; i < str.length; i+=2 )
{
  // alternatively document.body
  somediv.innerHTML += str.substr(i,2) + "<br>";
  console.log(str.charAt(i)+str.charAt(i+1));
}

//group 2 characters into 1 group and wrap it with a div
```

Next time, be more specific whether you want help on the wrap or adding stuff to DOM elements, pup. I'd be glad to instruct you how to use it if you can be clearer about what you want.

**Edit for jQuery tip:** I guess you could do something like:

```
$( "body" ).append("<div>" + str.substr(i,2) + "</div>");
```

refer to https://jsbin.com/sapukazidi/edit for code:

I guess you can use "wrap" if it proves to be better in performance than adding the divs right through html in append function. From the docs, it seems to have the sole function of wrapping an already existing element into a div or the tag of your choice, really. (< b >,< i >,< p >, et al)

Also, check this out: [Wrap Text In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript)
Feel free to use it to your liking if it applies.

Edit #2: or, just do it with spans.

> [fiddle with me](https://jsbin.com/dikiwiqiri/edit)

Comment: I hope we should use `<span>` than using `<br>` tag.