# It is possible to do a script where after every fitth word it enters a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, paragraph

I really need a script that can do my work easier because I am working with many words.

I want this script to put a maximum of words in my paragraph and everytime the words in a paragraph come to 5 the script will enter a new paragraph.

Let's say I have these 11 words.
**apple table chair house computer bottle pen window flower ship box**

I want my script to arrange them like this

> apple table chair house computer
>
> bottle pen window flower ship
>
> box

hope you get it.

If i put 14 words will look like this 
**apple table chair house computer bottle pen window flower ship box button mouse book**

> apple table chair house computer
>
> bottle pen window flower ship
>
> box button mouse book

then i will put 16

**apple table chair house computer bottle pen window flower ship box button mouse book calendar cable**

> apple table chair house computer
>
> bottle pen window flower ship
>
> box button mouse book calendar
>
> cable

If it's possible I would really love if someone can help me. Must say I am not a programmer but if someone will give me this script I know how to use it for sure.

Comment: while we really share love, you could try to add an attempt for the solution. you ight have a look here, too: [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't know what u trying to say. I really don't know if it's even possible but I imagine a function like:

If words = 5 in a paragraph ->insert new paragraph and so on. More than that i really can't help :(

Comment: also, I searched on that area, nothing that helps me.

Comment: some questions: where dies the words come from? are they in a html page with a special tag around, or in an textarea, where you like to format them, or just an array which should be renderen in html for an output?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. If you have written code for this that you can't get to work, then you have come to the right place. Just [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46642012/edit) and add the relevant parts of your code into it. You need to show your own efforts, because Stack Overflow is not a write-my-code-for-me service. Please see [ask].

Comment: I have them like this:@ clintbatac_art @ luxurianiya @ raulwhately @ evanyiri @ ix_nattan @ juan.espz @ jqwerhj @ noorasgirl @ yangduoduo616 @ mintgreendemon  and I want them to be placed in a paragraph. And the paragraph to stop at the every fifth word (without space between the @ and the word)

Answer (score 3):

Using JavaScript, you can match a word like this `\w+`, which will match any sequence of consecutive letters, digits, or underscores. Also, `\s*` will match one or more consecutive spaces. So `\w+\s*` matches a word, and `\w+\s*{5}` matches 5 words. We capture this string of 5 words using `$1`, and add a newline `\n` at the end of it.

```js
var string = "apple table chair house computer bottle pen window flower ship box button mouse book calendar cable";

var newString = string.replace(/((\w+\s*){5})/g, "$1\n");

console.log(newString);
```

Comment: this is the one!!!! thank youuu!! I searched the internet up and down, left and right and I couldnt find this.

Answer (score 2):

```js
    var your_text = "apple table chair house computer bottle pen window flower ship";
    var newtext = your_text.replace(/((\w+\W+\s*){5})/ig,"$1\n");
    console.log(newtext)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more complex solutions like regex or functions but try this simple one.

```js
var texts = 'apple table chair house computer bottle pen window flower ship box';
var myarray = texts.split(" ");
var words = texts.split(' ').length;
var colwords=[];
var count_to_5=0;
for (var i = 0; i < words; i++) {
  colwords.push(myarray[i]);
  if (count_to_5==5){
    var ll = colwords.toString();
    var re = new RegExp(',', 'g');
    $(".rr").append("<p>" + ll.replace(re,' ') + "</p>");
    count_to_5=0;
    colwords=[];
  } 
  count_to_5++;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rr"></div>
```

Comment: you never reach the end of the loop.

Comment: @NinaScholz Jup

Comment: Fixed, check it now.

Answer (score 1):

if you actually what to insert p tags instead of just a new line you can try this:

```js
var container = document.getElementById('container');
//get the text content
var text = container.innerText || container.textContent;
//split the text by spaces, any number of spaces
var words = text.split(/\s+/);
//empty the container
container.innerHTML = "";
words.forEach(function(word,index){
 if(index%5 == 0){ //if current index is a multiple of 5
   p = document.createElement("p");
    container.append(p);
  }
  p.innerHTML += word+" "; 
});
```

```html
<div id="container">
apple table chair house computer bottle pen window flower ship box button mouse book calendar cable
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Solution To Cut string As You Like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
       <head>
          <title>Page Title</title>
              </head>
        <body>
        <div id="stuff">a reallly really really long titleasdfasd fasdfasdfasdfasdfasdfadsf</div> 
        <script>
              function cutToString(id, Lenth){    
                var text = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
                var charsToCutTo = Lenth;
                  if(text.length>charsToCutTo){
                  var strShort = "";
                      for(i = 0; i < charsToCutTo; i++){
                         strShort += text[i];
                  }
                  document.getElementById(id).title = "text";
                  document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = strShort + "...";
               }            
         };

        cutToString('stuff', 40); 
    </script>

   </body>
 </html>
```

Where cutToSting is function to pass your text using "ID" and String Length

Answer (score 0):

[This should insert a line break at the nearest whitespace of maxChar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript)

Look at this resource to get some idea on how you would like your function to work. I would recommend setting a counter called whitespaces to 0 and running the loop and check for a white space character in the string. Whenever the 5th space occurs (check mod 5) add a '\n' character to the string in that position and continue.

Would really like to recommend also searching more thoroughly before asking a question. Hope this helps !

Comment: this one sounds easier than what I want but can it really help me when I have to copy&paste tousands of words?

Comment: yeah the size should not matter,only might affect the way it appears in the 'DOM' (Document Object Model) as long as you style it correctly. Anyway   since all solutions would have you go through the entire string either way your time complexity would remain the same.