# X-Axis title is getting cut when it is too long in AmCharts

Tags: javascript, charts, title, amcharts

I am using AmCharts library for creating multiple visualisations in my application and I came across this issue which is troubling me from past few weeks. This is happening particularly on mobile devices.

When the X-Axis or Y-Axis title is long it is getting cut on both sides. I have checked for an option to autowrap the titles but didn't find any luck on it. I know the labels can be auto-wrapped but not the title. Is there any option in AmCharts to resolve this issue?

Attaching the screenshot of the issue
[image]

Comment: AmCharts doesn't provide an autowrap option for titles. You have to write your own logic to accomplish this by adding newlines where needed.

Comment: You are mentioning about editing the core library of AmCharts?

Comment: No you should never modify the core. Write logic that preprocesses your string before assigning it to your chart's axes. Make an external function and assign the result to your chart axis title (i.e. `categoryAxis: { title: wordWrap(yourstring), ... }`). Here's an [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript) with sample implementations.