# Break line when string reaches X characters

Tags: javascript

I created this function below to calculate when a string (name) reaches more than 35 characters then it break a line.

```js
function getName(name) {
      let newName = name
      for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i += 1) {
        if (i % 35 === 0) {
          newName = `${newName.substr(0, i)}\n${newName.substr(i)}`
        }
      }
      return newName
}

console.log(getName("Please note that popular names below"))
```

Eg output:

```
Name = "Please note that popular names below"
function output:

Please note that popular names bel
ow
```

What I want is to instead of break a line of these two last characters "ow", I put "below" in the next line.

Comment: Is this for use on an HTML page and are you open to CSS or is this just for pure JavaScript?

Comment: It had to be pure javascript, it's a vue-js page.

Comment: Given your comment, this is a duplicate: Does this answer your question? [Wrap Text In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to break a string to certain length without cutting off any word, following code can help you:

```
const name = "YOUR_STRING";
const maxLen = 35; // you can play with this number to get desired result.

let result = name.substr(0, maxLen);
result = result.substr(0, Math.min(result.length, result.lastIndexOf(" ")));
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to find the last space within the first 35 characters and break the line there, right?

You can first slice the first 35 characters and then use regex to find the last space.

To slice the first 35 characters, use `name.substr(0,35)`. This returns a new string with the first 35 characters.

A regular expression that matches the last space is e.g. `/ (?!.* )/`, so you can do `replace(/ (?!.* )/, x)` where x is whatever you want (new line, in this case).

Answer (score 0):

You can I guess keep track of the last white space index, and then when reaching 35, break the line at the white space index

```
function getName(name) {
  let newName = name
  let wsIndex = 0
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i += 1) {
    if (name.charAt(i) == ' ') wsIndex = i;
    if (i % 35 === 0) {
      newName = `${newName.substr(0, wsIndex)}\n${newName.substr(wsIndex+1)}`
    }
  }
  return newName
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a simple solution, you simply have to look if the 35th character is a space(' '). If yes simply cut but if it isn't go back in the string until you hit a space, and cut there. My solution puts a line break if there are no spaces in the first 35 characters. Btw your code did copy the space to the next line, then you would have a small offset at every line.

The code:

```js
function getName(name) {
  let newName = name;
  // offsets i to match the current string
  let offset = 0;

  for (let i = 1; i < name.length; i += 1) {
    if (i % 35 === 0) {
      if(newName.charAt(i) === ' ') {
        // Your own code with the offset
        newName = newName = `${newName.substr(0, i - offset)}\n${newName.substr(i - offset + 1)}`;
      } else {
        // looking back in the string until there is a space or the string "ends"
        while(newName.charAt(i - offset) !== ' ' && offset <= 35) {
          offset++;
        }

        // Only set newName if a space was found in the last 35
        if(i - offset > 0) {
          newName = `${newName.substr(0, i - offset)}\n${newName.substr(i - offset + 1)}`;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return newName;
}

console.log(getName("Please note that popular names below"));
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ug5vpn8L/)

I tried to explain in the comments what i did and why.