# Wrapping text in Javascript - Need help using existing good answer

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to wrap simple text in a `<span>` object by getting its innerText (which I can do) and replacing it with text that has been wrapped even if only with `\n` used in place for new lines.

[I've found this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript) But there wasn't an example provided of how to use it.

```
// Static Width (Plain Regex)
const wrapFuntion = (s) => s.replace(
    /(?![^\n]{1,32}$)([^\n]{1,32})\s/g, '$1\n'
);
```

Lets say my string is defined as below

```
let stringName = "Here is my really long string, that I want to wrap every 20 or so characters"
let maxChars = 20; // Max number of characters on each line

let newString = wrapFuntion(stringName, maxChars);
```

From the comments on the answer it's probably easy for anyone with JavaScript experience, or I've missed something most find obvious in the answer. Just looking to learn.

*my score is too low to comment on original answer*

Comment: What is `wrapNum` supposed to be? The `wrap()` function only takes one argument. And it doesn't add a `<span>`

Comment: There is `wrap(stringName, wrapNum)` overload in that thread. Just call it.

Comment: Num wrap is the maximum number of characters I want on each line. The span thing is where I am getting the text from but isn't important but the case is something like `let stringName = document.getElementById('spanID').innerText;`, then I'll run `document.getElementById('spanID').innerText=wrapFuntion(stringName, wrapNum)` to replace the text. I'm not looking to add in `<span>`, just want to add a new line character `\n` where the text should wrap.

Comment: You know it, as you yourself used `let newString = wrapFuntion(stringName, maxChars);` in the question. Replace `wrapFuntion` with `wrap`. This is a typo question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I know how to call functions. What I didn't know was that it was a function (now learnt that it's an arrow function) and the syntax behind it. I'm trying to learn, it's not something I had come across before and understood. I am fairly comfortable with the standard `function fName(arg1,arg2)` syntax  for defining a function. Know it sounds dumb but I needed help with something as simple as understanding the notation. I did look up what `=>` meant but I found the information quite technical and it went over my head. Sorry, I'll try to phrase the question better in future.

Answer (score 0):

Use the code right below the static code, the one that says dynamic code

```js
// Dynamic Width (Build Regex)
const wrap = (s, w) => s.replace(
    new RegExp(`(?![^\\n]{1,${w}}$)([^\\n]{1,${w}})\\s`, 'g'), '$1\n'
);
```

since you want to specify the line length.

```js
// Dynamic Width (Build Regex)
const wrap = (s, w) => s.replace(
    new RegExp(`(?![^\\n]{1,${w}}$)([^\\n]{1,${w}})\\s`, 'g'), '$1\n'
);

const bob = document.getElementById("bob");

let stringName = bob.innerText;
let wrapNum = 20;

let newString = wrap(stringName, wrapNum);

bob.innerText = newString;
```

```html
<span id="bob">Here is my really long string, that I want to wrap every 20 or so characters</span>
```

Comment: Great example. This is what I was looking for, I didn't understand how to call the function in the original answer. The syntax of `wrap = (s, w) => s.replace(..` is not familiar to me yet.

Comment: @scryptonight They're called [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)