# regex from Javascript to google sheets

Tags: javascript, regex, google-sheets

I'm trying to get this regex to google sheets.
[Wrap Text In JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14484787/wrap-text-in-javascript)

In the solution

```
const wrap = (s) => s.replace(
    /(?![^\n]{1,32}$)([^\n]{1,32})\s/g, '$1\n'
);
```

I'm trying to replace this function with the native `REGEXREPLACE` to make it run faster. I have tried a few combinations but it all gives me the `Function REGEXREPLACE parameter 2 value " /(?![^\n]{1,32}$)([^\n]{1,32})\s/g" is not a valid regular expression.` with `=REGEXREPLACE(AP18," /(?![^\n]{1,32}$)([^\n]{1,32})\s/g","$1\n")` error.

I have also tried:
`=REGEXREPLACE(AP18,"(?![^\n]{1,32}$)([^\n]{1,32})\s","$1\n")`

same result

Can I not move it to a native Google function? or is there something wrong with my regex?

Comment: Yeah it seems that the regex is invalid for google sheets. No idea why though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use a quirky workaround when using `REGEXREPLACE` with newline in the replacement part: The `"\n"` newline does not work, so you have to enter a literal newline:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(D$7,"([^\n]{32}[^\s]{1,32})","$1
")
```

To do that, place the cursor to the right place in the replacement part, and hit CTRL+ENTER.

Note that I don't use a lookahead. That is because built-in functions only support the RE2 regex syntax, not the full one of the V8 JavaScript engine.

Alternatively, create a custom function under Extension => Apps Script. Here are two variants:

```
function WRAP1(str) {
  return str.replace(/(?![^\n]{1,32}$)([^\n]{1,32})\s/g, '$1\n');
}

function WRAP2(str) {
  return str.replace(/([^\n]{32}[^\s]{1,16})/g, '$1\n');
}
```

I prefer the latter because it wraps a superSuperSuperSuperSuperSuperSuperSuperSuperSuperSuperSuperLongWordToo.

Comment: the functions are too slow... i get this `loading...` , the built in is instant. Thumbs up for that. thanks.

Comment: @jason: I believe the initial slow loading is just to initialize. The function should run fast over thousands of uses.

Answer (score 1):

The RE2 regex engine used by Google Sheets `regex` functions [purposefully omits look-ahead and look-behind](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/WhyRE2). That means that the `(?!...)` assertion is not supported by `regexreplace()`.

It is usually possible to write an alternative regex that does not use those features. A full solution may involve several nested regex functions.

To learn the exact [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) syntax used by the regex functions in Google Sheets, see [RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Note that the `query()` spreadsheet function uses [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) that *do* support look-ahead and look-behind. Also note that Google Apps Script uses [JavaScript regexes](https://regexr.com/) that support those assertions as well.

Comment: Worth noting: The RE2 regex engine limitation only applies to built in functions. In custom scripts you can use the full regex supported by the V8 engine

Comment: Right. Apps Script is JavaScript and therefore has JavaScript regexes. The built-in `query()` function has look-ahead and look-behind as well. Edited the answer.